# Must Android app names be unique?

Tags: android, google-play

Can I release an Android app to Google Play if an app of the same name (not mine) already exists? Must names be unique (first come first served) or does Google Play let 'the free market' decide which one deserves the name?

Comment: There are 2 different things: the Java package and the Android Application package. The second one needs to be Unique. Refer this page for more information : http://blog.javia.org/android-package-name/

Comment: At least search ``IQ Test`` reveals multiple apps with same name. So I'm assuming application name doesn't have to be unique.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  However, it says `..conflict over the Application package ... and that’s why it is recommended to use the Java package name convention ("com.mydomain.myapp") for the Application package name as it avoids conflict.` That makes it sounds like the 'Application package' needs to be unique, but not the app name?

Comment: My question would be liability for using the same name as another app. Many apps have the same name as my game app, could I force them all to change names since I was first? Should I be concerned with liability if I start a new app with the same name as app that has less then 100 downloads?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can release an app named the exact same title string as another app, the package name (in reverse web URL format) is what keeps it unique, for example com.yourwebsite.yourappname or com.yourwebsite.yoursuitename.yourappname, but I would suggest a creative name for something going on the market!

Comment: I've got a creative name.. but someone else does too ;) The name is perfect but there another unrelated app with < 100 downloads and very bad reviews. Because of that, if I can use the same name I don't think the conflict would confuse.

Comment: But that doesn't answer the question as to what Google does if two developers from different companies attempt to use the same package name. What's to prevent two devs from uploading an app with  a package like com.mycompany.myapp? Does the second developer who attempts to upload get a warning that it has already been taken?

Comment: @AndroidDev - A long-standing convention is that you derive your package name from a domain name that you have the right to use. (See, for instance the [Java tutorial on naming packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html).) Nothing prevents a bad actor from using an app package name that starts with, say, `com.microsoft` (but to what end?), but I suspect that this use could be successfully challenged on intellectual property grounds, and they might even face financially liability. Internally, companies need to have their own conventions to avoid collisions.

Answer (score 12):

Google Play allows many apps to have the same title. However, the application package for each app needs to be unique within Google Play. This is the `package` attribute value that you provide for the `<manifest>` tag in the AndroidManifest.xml file of your project. From [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#package):

> The package name serves as a unique identifier for the application.

which then continues:

> **Caution:** Once you publish your application, you **cannot change the package name**. The package name defines your application's identity, so if you change it, then it is considered to be a different application and users of the previous version cannot update to the new version.