# Does same package name APK(with different applicationId) use same data location?

Tags: android, android-studio

we know APK save data in /data/data/PackageName，if two different apk with same package name,will they cover other's data?(like sharepreference's  data)

Comment: same package name is not possible!

Comment: you can try create 2 packages with same name and deploy into same phone/ emulator :)

Comment: First, check if you can install two APK's with the same package name. Which is not possible.

Comment: guys,you can install two APK with same package name but different applicationId

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is No, Why? This is not possible, Play store will not let you to upload an apk with the same package,Package name at play store is important for many reasons, one of them is update detection, if you updated an application the first  thing Google pay attention is the package name in order to know what is the current release version.

Somehow it will be happened by same developer at the **DEVELOPMENT** stage only then you can name your package whatever do you want.

Comment: the Play store which I upload APK allows developer upload same package name but different applicationId.

Comment: please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14346546/must-android-app-names-be-unique

Comment: I'm in China,bro.

Comment: so I'm not upload APK to google store,Chinease Play store has different rules

Comment: can you please listing them to me ? or give me a link]

Comment: How could you be so obstinate

Comment: Man i just need a link to improve my knowledge

Answer (score 0):

As far as same package name is concerned it's not possible to have installed on same device **it will be replaced**.

But if we have different appliationId, yes another app can be installed on same device but in that case packageName will also be change.

## Working Sample

### Project 1

**app/build.gradle**

```
applicationId  "com.test.sample"
```

**Android Manifest**

```
package="com.test.sample"
```

**Result**

When i print applicationId and package name, it was same:

applicationId: "com.test.sample"

package: "com.test.sample"

### Project 2

I've added buildTypes/flavor but keeping applicationId and package name same, but in that case outpout of applicationId and package name will be changed.

**build.gradle(app)**

```
applicationId "com.test.sample"
buildTypes {
    release {
        applicationIdSuffix ".release"
    }
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }
}
```

**Android Manifest**

```
package="com.test.sample"
```

**Result**

When i print applicationId and package name, it was different:

applicationId: "com.test.sample.debug"

package: "com.test.sample.debug"

So that is how two applications are installed due to change in buildType/flavors(pro/free).

And if you want to access sharedPreferences of each-other (assume free/pro version) than you need to create a ContentProvider to expose data you need and grant permissions to paid app.